# Executing two callbacks of two subscribers parallelly. How?

Tags: ros, callback, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If one sub1.callback is on execution and meanwhile msg arrives on other sub2. I want to process sub2.callback parallely. Is it possible? How?

```
ros::Subscriber image_sub= nh.subscribe("/rgb, 2, &class::imCallback, &class);
ros::Subscriber depth_sub= nh.subscribe("/depth", 2, &class::depthCallback, &class);
```

I read many posts on callback queues, MultiThreadedSpinner, boost. I am confused which way is good for my application !!

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319272/executing-two-callbacks-of-two-subscribers-parallelly.-how?/) by [JeyP4](https://answers.ros.org/users/38257/jeyp4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2019-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use `ros::MultiThreadedSpinner`: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning to execute multiple callbacks in parallel.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JeyP4](https://answers.ros.org/users/38257/jeyp4/) on 2019-03-22**:
Thanks @ahendrix
So, seperate callback queues for each subscriber is not required?